# python child process breaks following raw_input

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm writing a script that interacts with an interactive shell script briefly, and I stumbled across a problem where the subprocess that interacts with the interactive shell script would end but then hang, and when you hit enter, it would skip the `raw_input()` call that came immediately after the subprocess ran.

My Code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess;
import os;
import sys;
import time;

# Set up constants
GP_HOST = "1.1.1.1:5432";
GP_USER = "admin";
GP_PASS = "password";

PG_HOST = "2.2.2.2:5432";
PG_USER = "admin";
PG_PASS = "password";

# Collect required information from the user
new_client_name = raw_input('New Client Name (Also DB Name): ');
# Ensure there were no typos in the new client name
name_okay = raw_input("Is the name '"+new_client_name+"' okay? (Y/N): ");

while name_okay.upper() != "Y":
        new_client_name = raw_input('New Client Name (Also DB Name): ');
        name_okay = raw_input("Is the name '"+new_client_name+"' okay? (Y/N): ");

# Start the interactive Database script, and create new Greenplum/PostgreSQL databases
clone_child = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/scripts/startBuilder.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell='true');
clone_child.stdin.write("connect greenplum "+GP_HOST+" "+GP_USER+" "+GP_PASS+"\n");
clone_child.stdin.write("create "+new_client_name+"\n");
clone_child.stdin.write("disconnect\n");
clone_child.stdin.write("connect postgresql "+PG_HOST+" "+PG_USER+" "+PG_PASS+"\n");
clone_child.stdin.write("create "+new_client_name+"\n");
clone_child.stdin.write("disconnect\n");
clone_child.stdin.write("exit\n");

# Flush out stdin, close the subprocess, and wait for the main program to resume
clone_child.stdin.flush();

# Request the Client details needed to add the client to CEA
auth_host = raw_input('Enter Authhost with Port: ');

client_version = raw_input('Client Version to Create: ');

clone_client = raw_input('Clone an existing client? (Y/n): ');
...
```

I had tried putting `clone_child.stdin.close();` after my flush call, and it still hangs and skips the first `raw_input()` call.

I suppose it's just a hard problem to phrase, as I couldn't find any other questions with the same issue as mine, though I suspect that may be due to how I phrased the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this finally, thanks to this link: [Writing to a python subprocess pipe](https://gist.github.com/waylan/2353749#file-subprocess_pipe-md)

I added

```
clone_child.stdin.close();
clone_child.wait();
```

after my `clone_child.stdin.flush();` call. and now it properly closes out the child process. As you can see, I also added back in the `clone_child.stdin.close()` call for good measure.

Hopefully this helps the next person who finds themselves with this issue.

Comment: Tip: Python has no need of semicolons at the ends of lines.  Having them doesn't contribute anything positive to the code.

Comment: Ah, I actually am aware of this. I just do a lot of JS coding and it's habit.